# Lazy-loading Vue components from a components API

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, lazy-loading, web-component

So, I'm working in a plugin system project and my team is using Vuejs. As I've projected we will need to lazy-load the components from an API.

How can we do this with Vuejs?

The components are going to be developed from some base classes(that inherits from vue base component class) that we are going to provide to third-party developers and their components will be hosted by one HTTP API.

We want to make a call like

```
GET /me/plugins
```

And receive a JSON with all the plugins of the current user and then load this into our main Vue app.

**EDIT**

The JSON will look something like this:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "MyPlugin",
      "description": "This is my plugin",
      "src": "http://plugin-api.com/plugins/5/plugin.min.js
    },
    {...},
    {...},
  ]
}
```

And I was thinking in instantiating this "plugins"(new features developed in vuejs as pluggable components) that are fetched from the API in runtime.

So as the user **LOGIN** we will fetch **ALL THE USER'S PLUGINS** and **INSTALL** them on the UI.

Do using the `import` keyword pointing to outside really works?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by Lazy Load, would that be on demand?

Take a look at this VueJs lib if, if it worked for you, they have a demo (using images), but maybe their code can help you.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-lazyload

Comment: I've checked this module! And I think this could work, but I want to check this strategy with other devs. I've edited the post for clarity

Comment: @gbrennon were you able to accomplish this?